# White Space List to Heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I need to make a heatmap style plot (the data is evenly separated so I don't think the plotting method should matter much) from some data pulled from an HTML tool. Unfortunately the tool gives all the data points as a 3 row whitespace separated list in the form of a .xyz file. For example...

```
-1 -1 .2
-1  0 .5
-1  1 .9
-1  2 .7
0  -1  0
0   0 .8
0   1 .1
0   2 .9
1  -1 .5
1   0 .4
1   1 .6
1   2 .7
```

I suspect that the best method is to put the file into a dataframe, do the wrangling, then use `sns.heatmap()` or some method for the plotting. To do this I'm currently first re-saving the files to .csv, and then importing with `pandas.read_csv()` (I feel there must be a more pythonic way to complete these steps).  <strike>I have used `pandas.unique()` to grab column and index values. Now, I'm at a loss for a way to build and populate the new dataframe correctly.</strike>

### Solution so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

header = ['x', 'y', 'value']
df_demo = pd.read_csv(r"C:\MyLocation\\"
                      +'democsv'+'.csv', header = None, delim_whitespace=True)
df_demo.columns = header

df_pivot = df_demo.pivot(index='y',columns='x', values='value')

sns.heatmap(df_pivot)
```

### Output

[Output from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6uz1.png)

I'm open to solving this other ways, and thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pivot`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=header, delim_whitespace=True)

df_pivot = df.pivot(index='x',columns='y', values='value')


import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df_pivot)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Doh! Thanks for the almost immediate answer. I was going to edit your response as it flips the x, and y as I have it from above. Otherwise, this is great.